# how to delete app from app store

Tags: iphone, app-store

how to delete app from app store? I don't find any link there. Where is the link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You go to iTunes Connect, select manage applications, select the app you want to delete > rights and pricing> deselect all app stores.

This will set your app to 'developer removed from sale'.

I believe you can delete the app entirely after this, and the 'delete app' button should now be added to the first screen after you select the app. If you do delete the app, you will never be able to use the app name again. If you plan on using it, just 'developer removed from sale'.

Comment: @W Dyson Thanks for your answer. A precision: I just read from the "iTunesConnect_Guide" -> "After the app is deleted, your app name can be used by another developer." (but I don't have any information about the delai)

Comment: I Tried to remove an app that is not submitted to store but in the ready to upload binary state can you please tell me how to remove that app and also the above steps is not working now

Answer (score 1):

In iTunesConnect, go to Manage Your Applications, select the application, select Rights and Pricing, don't select any stores.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Apps cannot be deleted until there is one approved version. If there is not an approved version, the app record can NOT be deleted.

The "delete app" button will just not be there in this case. So don't create an App for "testing" and expect you can remove it later on !